# In lean, how to work around "invalid pattern, 'x' already appeared in this pattern"

Tags: lean

I am trying to define what it means for an item to be in a list. I wrote this case breakdown:

```
inductive NatList : Type
| nil : NatList
| cons : nat → NatList → NatList

def contains : nat -> NatList -> Prop
| _ NatList.nil := false
| x (NatList.cons x _) := true   -- error here
| x (NatList.cons _ tail) := contains x tail
```

On the `| x (NatList.cons x _) := true` line I get the error `invalid pattern, 'x' already appeared in this pattern`. I can see that I have in fact used `x` twice. But that's because I actually want it to pattern match to the case where the list item matches the query item. How do I rephrase what I want in a way that Lean will accept?

Comment: You need to convince Lean that equality on natural numbers is decidable. It is not the case for e.g. real numbers, so the definition would be `uncomputable`.

Comment: @Trebor you can safely assume that if I am struggling with syntax errors, "convince Lean equality is decidable" is beyond my current ability to turn from an abstract goal into concrete steps. Also, I would have assumed the built-in nat would already do things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I know of is this:

```
def contains : nat -> NatList -> Prop
| _ NatList.nil := false
| x (NatList.cons y tail) := 
  if x = y then 
    true
  else 
    contains x tail
```

Note that for Lean to decide if `x = y` is true, you need equality to be decidable, like it is for `nat`.  If you replace `nat` with another type without decidable equality like `nat -> nat`, then this definition will fail.  I assume it is for subtle reasons like this that Lean doesn't support the notation you had in mind.

Edit: Actually, if you are working with `Prop`, you likely don't care about computability and decidability.  Further, the general `list` version of this is in the library as [`list.mem`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/data/list/basic.html#list.mem) with definition:

```
protected def mem : α → list α → Prop
| a []       := false
| a (b :: l) := a = b ∨ mem a l
```

Comment: Argh, I actually *tried* the one with `∨` but I was tricked by my editor that it was wrong! The online editor at https://leanprover.github.io/live/latest happens to do a bad substitution for `\/` in this context, and it leaves behind *sneaky zero-width unprintable characters* that were the actual syntax error (as opposed to using `\/` causing the error which was what I thought was happening).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use x multiple times during a pattern match you need to use .(x) for each additional appearance of x. But even after fixing this Lean complains that equation 3 isn't being used in the compilation (not sure what is happening here).